# How to set root password to null

Tags: mysql

How can I change the password for `root` user of MySQL to `null` -- meaning no password or `''` -- from the MySQL command line client?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can recover MySQL database server password with following five easy steps.

**Step # 1**: Stop the MySQL server process.

**Step # 2**: Start the MySQL (mysqld) server/daemon process with the --skip-grant-tables option so that it will not prompt for password.

**Step # 3**: Connect to mysql server as the root user.

**Step # 4**: Setup new mysql root account password i.e. reset mysql password.

**Step # 5**: Exit and restart the MySQL server.

Here are commands you need to type for each step (login as the root user):

**Step # 1** : Stop mysql service

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Output:

```
Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
```

**Step # 2**: Start to MySQL server w/o password:

```
# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Output:

```
[1] 5988
Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
mysqld_safe[6025]: started
```

**Step # 3**: Connect to mysql server using mysql client:

```
# mysql -u root
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1 to server version: 4.1.15-Debian_1-log
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.
mysql>
```

**Step # 4**: Setup new MySQL root user password

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

**Step # 5**: Stop MySQL Server:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Output:

```
Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld
STOPPING server from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
mysqld_safe[6186]: ended
[1]+  Done                    mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

**Step # 6**: Start MySQL server and test it

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql start
# mysql      
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) 
# mysql -u root -p
```

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html

Comment: This link doesn't actually tell you how to set it to null, which is what the original post was about.

Comment: @y0mbo: Can't you just `update user set password=PASSWORD("") where User='root';`?

Comment: @y0mbo Pasted quotation into the answer.

Comment: Step 1 and 2 are not necessary (the question doesn't say that the previous password was lost or forgotten), step 4 is wrong because the question asks how to set a blank password, it should be `update user set password=PASSWORD('') where User='root';` if using MySQL 5.5.46 or newer and `update user set password=null where User='root';` if using older versions.

Comment: mysql 5.7 doesn't have `password` field in the `mysql.user` table... any suggestions...

Comment: I come again a long time after this issue was created but with MariaDB 10.0.22 it does not work at all, either with "password=PASSWORD('')" or "password=null"...
:(

Comment: @DimitryK The `password` column is `authentication_string` in newer versions.

Comment: @GustavoStraube It's about 7 years old.

Answer (score 95):

Worked for me and  "5.7.11 MySQL Community Server":

```
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';
```

I had to change the 'plugin' field as well because it was set to 'auth_socket'.

After that I could connect as `mysql -u root` without a password.

Comment: `plugin='mysql_native_password'` was the key bit for me.

Comment: I needed to do `flush privileges` afterwards too.

Comment: Thanks worked for me in 5.17, you need to restart mysql after using this method to see the affects of changes. `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: This worked on `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.28-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Comment: Weird enough, I have to do this after each upgrade of mysql. That said, this is my one liner: `sudo mysql -uroot mysql -e 'update user set authentication_string=password(""), plugin="mysql_native_password" where user="root";flush privileges;'`

Comment: This also works with MariaDb 10.1 (with a 3rd command `flush privileges;` ). All other solution above didn't.

Answer (score 57):

If you want an empty password, you should set the password to null and not use the Password hash function, as such:

On the command line:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -uroot
```

In MySQL:

```
use mysql;
update user set password=null where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1048. Column 'Password' cannot be null

Comment: Worked for me with password=null - setting password to '' did NOT work. I am using MySQL 5.5.12.

Comment: `update user set password='' where User='root';` work for MySQL 5.6

Comment: I think [Zendo June's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46360020/1128918) is the best solution for this case.

Comment: flush privileges; is a must - conclusion after an hour of hacking around

Answer (score 54):

- connect to mysql as user root (use one of the two following methods)

  - login as root and start mysql using `mysql -p`, enter current root password
  - login as self and start mysql using `mysql -u root -p`, enter current root password
- `mysql> set password = password('');`

Done! No root password.

Comment: This did not work for me, I was unable to login as root afterwards no matter if I provided password or not. 
Setting password to null instead of '' worked for me. (Mysql 5.5.12)

Comment: Worked for me on MariaDB 10.3.9 - much easier than a lot of the advice about stopping the database, running with skip-grant-tables, etc etc!

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me with MariaDB 10.3.8. May be obvious but `mysql>` in the last step is the prompt.  You actually just run `set password = password('')`

Answer (score 22):

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('');
```

Comment: This is a more up-to-date answer

Comment: This is now deprecated, use `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = '';` instead.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with v5.7.15 MySQL:

First, make sure you have mysql-client installed (`sudo apt-get install mysql-client`).

Open terminal and login:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

(then type your password)

After that:

```
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';
```

(tnx @Stanislav Karakhanov)

And the very last important thing is to **reset mysql service**:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

You should now be able to login (without passsword) also by using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: It baffles me how many different ways there are to set the root password. None of them worked on my MySql 5.7.16 until this solution came along. Thank you.

Comment: problem with the default Ubuntu 16.04 installation of mysql-server (5.7) is that it uses a different `plugin` (namely `auth_socket`) for `root@localhost`. That's why `sudo mysql` will work, while `mysql -uroot` doesn't, since the latter command does *not* connect via the socket.

Answer (score 8):

For MySQL 8.0 just:

`SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = '';`

Answer (score 7):

It's not a good idea to edit `mysql` database directly.

I prefer the following steps:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ''; 
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Comment: This also works in case you get the following error: `ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

Answer (score 5):

This is from MySQL 8.0.13:

```
use mysql;

update user set authentication_string=null  where user='root';

quit;
```

Answer (score 4):

I noticed a few of these solutions above are now deprecated.

To set an empty password simply follow these steps:

```
mysql -u root -p

use mysql

SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = '';

\q (to quit)

now run: mysql -u root
```

You should be able to start mysql up without a password now.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me.

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by user64141

```
use mysql;
update user set password=null where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit;
```

didn't work for me in MariaDB 10.1.5 (supposed to be a drop in replacement for MySQL).  While didn't tested it in MySQL 5.6 to see if is an upstream change, the error I got was:

> ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'Password' cannot be null

But replacing the null with empty single or double quotes worked fine.

```
update user set password='' where User='root';
```

or

```
update user set password="" where User='root';
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using nodejs and windows 10. A combination of two answers worked for me.

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ''; 
mysql> flush privileges;
```

followed by:

```
restart;
```

Hope this helps for others who still have an issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your Root Password and just wish to reset it then do as below:

- Start MySQL Service from control panel > Administrative Tools > Services. (only if it was stopped by you earlier ! Otherwise, just skip this step)
- Start MySQL Workbench
- Type in this command/SQL line

  ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE;

To reset any other user password... just type other user name instead of root.

Answer (score 0):

For connect to mysql without password:

`mysql -p
SET PASSWORD = ""`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is slightly different depending on version. From the docs here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

MySQL 5.7.6 and later:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
```

MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('');
```

Answer (score 0):

My variant for MySQL 5.7:

Stop service mysql:

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
```

Running in Safe Mode:

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

(above line is the whole command)

Open a new terminal window:

```
$ mysql -u root

$ mysql use mysql;

$ mysql update user set authentication_string=password('password') where user='root';

$ mysql update user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User='root';

$ mysql flush privileges;
$ mysql quit;
```

Run the mysql service:

```
$ sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to put my own 2cents in here bcuz the above answers did not work for me.
On centos 7, mysql community v8, shell is bash.

The correct commands would be as follows:

```
# start mysql without password checking
systemctl stop mysqld 2>/dev/null
systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables" &&
systemctl start mysqld

# set default password to nothing
mysql -u root mysql <<- 'EOF'
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    UNINSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';
    ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    INSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';
EOF

# restart mysql normally
systemctl restart mysqld
```

then you can login without password:

```
mysql -u root
```

Answer (score 0):

its all because you installed greater then 5.6 version of the mysql

Solutions

1.you can degrade mysql version solution

2 reconfigure authentication to native type or legacy type authentication using
    configure option

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 19.10, mysql 8, this is what worked for me:

```
$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
$ mysql
> use mysql
> alter user set authentication_string='', plugin='mysql_native_password' where user = 'root';
> quit
$ sudo mysqladmin shutdown
$ sudo systemctl start mysql
```

If you get errors trying to run `mysqld_safe`, in particular: `/var/run/mysqld for UNIX socket file don't exists`, you can try creating the dir and running `mysqld_safe` again.

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo chgrp mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

Comment: It's `UPDATE user` not `ALTER user`.

Answer (score -2):

After searching for hours i found it . just Change the password to something contains Upper case numeric and special characters in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you read where the question asks how to set the root password to null, and the many existing answers that show that it can be done rather than changing the password to something that isn't null?