# ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE - sails 1.0 and MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I'm trying to connect SailsJS with MySQL

```
default: {
  adapter: require('sails-mysql'),
  url: 'mysql://root:root@localhost/ventas'
},
```

But whenever I do a 'sails lift' I get the following error:

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error:
error: { error:
   { Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\ticket\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:48:14) }
```

I'm just using the web app template that comes with sails with no added code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming from `mysql`, you need to change the plugin to `mysql_native_password` and then `flush privileges;`, see [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1507) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101694/how-to-set-root-password-to-null/36234358#36234358).

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be with encrypting the password. MySQL 8.0 uses caching_sha2_password. You need change it to mysql_native_password:

```
ALTER USER 'user' identified with mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Answer (score -2):

Set your password to one with  Upper case , lower case, numeric and a special character in it with 8 letters long .