# NodeJS MySQL Client does not support authentication protocol

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, backend

When I am trying to connect with mysql 8.0 I am getting this error. How can I fix this ?

```
code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
errno: 1251,
sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; 
consider upgrading MySQL client',
sqlState: '08004',
fatal: true
```

Comment: What's the auth protocol requested by the server and which one you are using - that's where you should look for

Comment: @Rupesh:  change the `plugin` field as well because it was set to 'auth_socket'.
`use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';`

Check this link: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946270/er-not-supported-auth-mode-mysql-server)

Comment: Solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101694/how-to-set-root-password-to-null/36234358#36234358

Comment: @Manav I am using mysql 8.0.11 and I have tried  `mysql> use mysql;
Database changed
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("helloworld") where User='root';`
And it says: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("helloworld") where User='root'' at line 1`

Comment: Please check your syntax/code. Error is related to this. [Click here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js can't authenticate to MySQL 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373427/node-js-cant-authenticate-to-mysql-8-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 8.0 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server)

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74458804/3944673

Answer (score 52):

Try change the password as below:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your new password'; 
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your new password';
```

Comment: Great answer! This solved my problem! Can you please explain why this works?

Comment: @Jessica MySQL 8.0 uses caching_sha2_password as default authentication plugin rather than MySQL 5.7 default mysql_native_password, supported by most clients, which is why you need to explicitly allow that authentication for given user:
    ALTER USER 'user' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'

Answer (score 13):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

"password" is that you have to change the password you already have or you will modify it for a new one

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade your Mysql to 5.7 to fix it