# MySQL 8: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE

Tags: mysql, node.js

### Setup

- Expressjs (Node) running in at *localhost:3000* on a Windows 10 PC.
- MySQL ran in a Docker container at 192.168.99.100:3306 via *docker-machine*.

#### Problem

When trying to connect server to MySQL using:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '192.168.99.100',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'foo123',
  database: 'foo_db'
});
```

Getting:

> Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgr
>   ading MySQL client

Checked many answer here at StackOverflow. Most of them use ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373427/node-js-cant-authenticate-to-mysql-8-0/50377944#50377944)):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyNewPass';
```

However I get:

> mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyNewPass';
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

And the server still doesn't want to connect. Using MySQL 5.7 works fine.

Any ideas how to fix this for MySQL 8?

---

**ADDED:**

Just to be crystal clear:

- Using official MySQL Docker: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/.
- server.js gist: https://gist.github.com/h3d0/8d021d25892f34976d806485f18479f2
- Running MySQL Docker gist: https://gist.github.com/h3d0/505f41a633f571e12117b32638035412
- Connection to MySQL Docker gist: https://gist.github.com/h3d0/aea7b48144d08403d69e2da3ccdcdde7

After connecting to MySQL, running:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'foo123';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Restarting Node.js and MySQL container and nothing happens.

Comment: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` ?

Comment: Tried that. And also tried adding new user.

Comment: This is basically a FAQ at this point. `update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where user = 'root'; flush privileges;` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101694/how-to-set-root-password-to-null/36234358#36234358

Comment: @dossy setting plugin like this seem to do the trick - `mysql_native_password` is set for both of my *root* users. However after that I am never allowed to connect to MySQL: *ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '172.17.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server*.

Comment: Going to just roll back to 5.7 until the dev-team fixes this properly. Don't want to use hacks for things that suppose to work right off the bat.

Comment: Did you create the user `root@'172.17.0.3'` or `root@'%'`?  Otherwise, I think the default is `root@'localhost'` and if you're not running your code inside the docker container that's running MySQL, you're not connecting from localhost.

Answer (score 8):

I hope you are not using literally the value `'MyNewPass'`, but it surely looks like it. That's supposed to be an example placeholder.

In your case you would have to do:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'foo123';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, have tried `foo123` as well. I wonder if the problem can be related to the fact that I am running MySQL from inside a Docker container.

Comment: Updated my description. If this doesn't help might just go for https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi for production.

Comment: The important part here is the `WITH mysql_native_password`.

Comment: `SELECT plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';` what does this tell you?

Comment: @ruiquelhas it returns: `+-----------------------+
| plugin                |
+-----------------------+
| caching_sha2_password |
| mysql_native_password |
+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)`