# Getting ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_CODE in connecting node.js to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I'm following a tutorial on the internet to learn MySQL through Node.js, but I'm unable to connect them. Here is the error I'm getting:

> code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
> errno: 1251,
> sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested
> by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',     sqlState: '08004',
> fatal: true

My code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "*******"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
else 
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

I have installed the MySQL driver using npm and I have just installed MySQL, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your MySQL installation and node's MySQL plugin used have incompatible authentication methods/protocols. Simplest solution is to ["downgrade" the protocol used on the db server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209514/what-is-mysql-native-password) - start your mysql client via `mysql` command and execute the following:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting root password as null?
[1]: [How to set root password to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101694/how-to-set-root-password-to-null/36234358#36234358)

Changing plugin to mysql_native_password may solved your problem.